# Corsair VOID Pro Sidetone

Tags: sound, microphone, headset

I just made the switch from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, and I was immediately greeted with the sidetone in my Corsair VOID Pro kicking back on. I can hear everything my microphone picks up which is pretty annoying. I heard that there wasn't much support for peripherals in Linux, but I was hoping there was some way to at least turn off the sidetone for the headset. Any solutions?

[Headset on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0748K7JW6)

EDIT: Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1532:0043 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:58b0 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 1532:0217 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1b1c:0a18 Corsair 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

[Output of journalctl --since="-3 minutes"](https://pastebin.com/4KVELBgH)

Comment: Please Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1148113/edit ) your question and add the results of (in a terminal ) `lsusb`, then, unplug the headset and plug it back in, wait 10 seconds and `journalctl --since="-3 minutes"` will show you log messages of interest.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable it with Sapd headset software,

https://github.com/Sapd/HeadsetControl

run

```
headsetcontrol -s 0
```

to completely disable it